# Subset larger than the matches

Tags: r, subset

I want to subset a dataframe I did this:

```
test = genes_names %in% annot2$Short_Name_Sc
summary(test)  # 3140 rows to subset
## Mode       FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
## logical    2146    3140       0 

test2 = annot2[test, 1]
nrow(annot2)
## [1] 5371
nrow(test2)
## [1] 3195 # There are 55 rows unexpected
```

To my surprise the `test2` object has more rows than `TRUE`s in `test` vector. I thought it could be something of subseting with `[]`.

And I tried with subset:

```
probe = subset(annot2, test, 1)
```

But it has the same number of rows than the previous code. Is there any explanation?

The data is quite big so I don't post it, and unfortunately I didn't manage to make a reproducible example. 
The data sets are all characters:

```
summary(annot2)
## Probe_ID         Short_Name_Sc      Systematic_Name_Sc
## Length:5371        Length:5371        Length:5371       
## Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
## Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character

summary(genes_names)
## Length     Class      Mode 
## 5286       character  character
```

Comment: Your example is fully non-reproducible. Additionally, you're using genes_names, annot2, test and annot2? Make it reproducible or at least show clear train of thought.

Comment: Maybe you want `test = annot2$Short_Name_Sc %in% genes_names`, which will return a logical vector indicating which of `Short_Name_Sc` are in `genes_names`.

Comment: @konvas `length(genes_names)[1] 5286 > nrow(annot2)[1] 5371` You are right. That means that the `%in%` and the `subset` omit the `<Na>`. And I should do so when subsetting with a `&` command. If you post in an answer I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is observed due to the different lengths of `genes_names` and `annot2[, 1]`, which cause the vector `test` to be partially recycled. The vectors `test` and `genes_names` have length 5286  but `nrow(annot2)` equals 5371. So when calling `annot2[test, 1]` the result is actually `annot2[c(test, test[1:85]), 1]` (the number 85 comes from the difference in lengths; 85 = 5371 - 5286).

A reproducible example using `mtcars`, which has 32 rows: If we define `test` to be some logical vector of length which does not divide 32, e.g. `test <- c(T, T, F, F, T)`, then `mtcars[test, 1]` is the same as `mtcars[c(rep(test, 6), test[1:2]), 1]` and has length 20. The vector `test` is recycled as many times as possible to fit into the 32 rows of mtcars (i.e. 6 times), returning 18 rows (since there are 3 `TRUE` values in `test`) plus 2 additional rows from the first two elements of `test` (since 32 = 2 mod 5).

Comment: If you make it more general it will help more people